# SQL - SUM on jointable together with AVG on foreign table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a database with the tables `Cities`, `Shops` and `Sales`, such that `Cities` has many `Shops` and `Shops` has many `Sales`.
`Shops` is basically a join table, such that `Cities` belongs to many `Sales`.

I am looking for a query to find the average sales price per city, along with the sum of employees.

I tried:

```
SELECT cities.id, AVG(sales.price) AS "avg_price", SUM(shops.employees) AS "tot_employees"
FROM cities
LEFT JOIN shops ON shops.city_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.shop_id = shops.id
GROUP BY city.id
-- 640 ms
```

However this sum returns far too many employees. Which makes sense, because there are many duplicate rows for `Shops` because of the second join.

Slightly better:

```
SELECT cities.id, AVG(sales.price) AS "avg_price", SUM(DISTINCT(shops.employees)) AS "tot_employees"
FROM cities
LEFT JOIN shops ON shops.city_id = city.id
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.shop_id = shops.id
GROUP BY city.id
-- 660 ms
```

Which only sums unique values for employees. However, this will be of course incorrect for shows that have an identical number of employees.

Note: the `Sales` table is rather large. Efficiency is important.

How to perform an aggregation query on each row of this intermediate join table, without duplicates, without affecting the destination table?

Comment: First aggregate, then join.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

How about two levels of aggregation?

```
SELECT c.id, SUM(sum_price) / SUM(num_sales), SUM(tot_employees)
FROM (SELECT c.id, sh.id as shop_id, SUM(s.price) AS sum_price, COUNT(*) as sales,
            sh.employees AS tot_employees
      FROM cities c LEFT JOIN
           shops sh
           ON sh.city_id = c.id LEFT JOIN
           sales s
           ON s.shop_id = sh.id
      GROUP BY c.id, sh.id
     ) c
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: It seems to work. However, the time this query takes is 26 seconds, compared to the 0.6 seconds of my original query. Why is this difference so large? Can this be avoided?

Comment: @Roberto . . . You would need to check the execution plans, but I suspect Postgres has an optimization because you are aggregating by the primary key of one table.